Printer aspect ratio incorrect
I changed to a new ISP. Afterwards, my printer (Epson ET-2800) stopped working from Ubuntu (oracular). After re-adding the printer, the print output is stretched 10% more in the vertical direction, so that circles become ovals. The outer box of the Ubuntu test page runs off the bottom of the paper. Printing from an iPad does not have this issue. I tried both the Ubuntu-provided PPD and the Epson-provided PPD, which made no difference.
Is there some settings menu with parameters for this? Or a control file?
(Ubuntu keeps adding an automatically added printer which does not work at all. I am using ipp.)

Is it just one application that is 10% off?  What if you print with another application?

I didn't think to check that. Atril prints a pdf just fine. Seems that the Ubuntu printer test page has issues. I have no idea what prints the Ubuntu test page, but maybe I don't care? Also, I updated to ocular since the last time I printed a test page, so it could be an Ubuntu bug.
